# Eclipse CDT - Copy, clean and build programmatically a C++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to duplicate a project, do some processing on the duplicated project and (clean &) build it automatically. I managed to write the code for duplicating a project (given below) but there are still some issues.

(i) .cproject file still has some remnant of the source project (Example instead of Example2) 
    e.g.,

`<builder buildPath="${workspace_loc:/Example}/Debug" id="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.builder.macosx.exe.debug.1434305598" keepEnvironmentInBuildfile="false" managedBuildOn="true" name="Gnu Make Builder" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.builder.macosx.exe.debug"/>`

Do I need to change anything in project description? Am I missing any command?

(ii) clean and build the project automatically

I looked into the CCorePlugin and CoreModel classes but couldn't find any suitable. 
Any idea how can I achieve this programmatically?

```
public static IProject copyProject(IProject project, String newProject) throws CoreException { 
    try{
        IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor(); 
        IWorkspaceRoot workspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(); 
        IProjectDescription projectDescription = project.getDescription(); 

        // create clone project in workspace 
        IProjectDescription cloneDescription = workspaceRoot.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription(newProject); 
        // copy project files 
        project.copy(cloneDescription, true, monitor); 
        IProject clone = workspaceRoot.getProject(newProject); 

        //make it a CPP project 
        CCorePlugin.getDefault().convertProjectToCC(clone, monitor, clone.getFullPath().toOSString()); 

        // copy the project properties 
        cloneDescription.setNatureIds(projectDescription.getNatureIds()); 
        cloneDescription.setReferencedProjects(projectDescription.getReferencedProjects()); 
        cloneDescription.setDynamicReferences(projectDescription.getDynamicReferences()); 
        cloneDescription.setBuildSpec(projectDescription.getBuildSpec()); 
        cloneDescription.setReferencedProjects(projectDescription.getReferencedProjects()); 
        clone.setDescription(cloneDescription, null); 
        return clone; 
    } 
    catch (CoreException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            MessageUtility.writeToConsole("console", e.getMessage()); 
            return null; 
    } 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this *standard* C++, C# or C++/CLI?

Comment: I believe the bulk of Eclipse and the CDT are written in Java.

Comment: As @user4581301 said, most (if not all) of the Eclipse CDT is in Java.

Comment: CDT supports duplicating a project by copying and pasting it in the Project Explorer. It may be helpful to look at the code that implements that action: http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/cview/PasteAction.java#n122.